Inconsistent results when running migrations in MongoDb
I wrote the "up" migration since we change a schema. When I run the command, however the migration is only partially applied. For example, there should be 4 affected records but only 1 or 2 or 3 are effectively changed, sometime none. To investigate I wrote some console logs in the function but, as above only some are printed (or none) and no errors arise. This is the function (when the changes apply the result is what I expect). I am new to MongoDb and the migration package and I am worried about this inconsistent outcome
Packages:
"migrate": "^2.1.0",
"mongoose": "^8.5.1",
module.exports.up = async () => {
  try {
    // Fetch SpecType documents that have instructions array not empty
    const specTypes = await SpecType.find({ instructions: { $exists: true, $ne: [] } }).lean();

    for (const specType of specTypes) {
      console.log('specType', specType);
      const newInstructions = [];
      await Promise.all(
        specType.instructions.map(async instruction => {
          let existingInstruction = await Instruction.findOne({ text: instruction });

          if (!existingInstruction) {
            existingInstruction = await new Instruction({ text: instruction }).save();
          }

          newInstructions.push({
            id: existingInstruction._id,
            text: existingInstruction.text
          });

          return Promise.resolve();
        })
      );
      console.log('NEW', newInstructions);
      await SpecType.updateOne({ _id: specType._id }, { $set: { instructions: newInstructions } });
    }

    console.log('Migration completed successfully.');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('An error occurred during migration:', error);
    throw error;
  }
};


You're using Promise.all inside the for...of loop, which creates parallel asynchronous operations, but you're also mutating the newInstructions array outside of it. This is problematic because array mutations might not align with the completion of the Promise.all operations. Instead of using Promise.all inside the for...of loop, you can process the instructions sequentially.
Also you're using .lean() when fetching SpecType documents. This makes them plain JavaScript objects, so they lose any Mongoose-specific methods like .save(). While this is fine for read-only operations, it might introduce confusion if you later try to modify the documents directly. I wouldn't do that
module.exports.up = async () => {
  try {
    // Fetch SpecType documents that have a non-empty instructions array
    const specTypes = await SpecType.find({ instructions: { $exists: true, $ne: [] } }).lean();

    for (const specType of specTypes) {
      console.log('Processing SpecType:', specType._id);

      const newInstructions = [];

      for (const instruction of specType.instructions) {
        let existingInstruction = await Instruction.findOne({ text: instruction });

        if (!existingInstruction) {
          existingInstruction = await new Instruction({ text: instruction }).save();
        }

        // Add the instruction to the new array
        newInstructions.push({
          id: existingInstruction._id,
          text: existingInstruction.text,
        });
      }

      // Log the updated instructions array
      console.log('Updated instructions for SpecType:', specType._id, newInstructions);

      // Update the SpecType document
      await SpecType.updateOne({ _id: specType._id }, { $set: { instructions: newInstructions } });
    }

    console.log('Migration completed successfully.');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('An error occurred during migration:', error);
    throw error;
  }
};


thanks for your reply and explanation. However, i have tried also with for loop inside the outer for loop but the result is the same :(. Regarding the lean(), I did't find any other way to access the content of the instructions fields, since the model has changed (from an array of simple string, it has become an array of objects, so if I don't use .lean() and I print the record's instructions i get something like this [{'1':'A', '2':'l', '3':'l',...}], with the former string broken into charachters
